# List not populated correctly unless use PyTorch clone()

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm attempting to add the final weights of each trained model to a list using below code :

```
%reset -f

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torch.utils.data as data_utils
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons
from matplotlib import pyplot
from pandas import DataFrame
import torchvision.datasets as dset
import os
import torch.nn.functional as F
import time
import random
import pickle
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import sklearn


trans = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(), transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (1.0,))])

root = './data'
if not os.path.exists(root):
    os.mkdir(root)
train_set = dset.MNIST(root=root, train=True, transform=trans, download=True)
test_set = dset.MNIST(root=root, train=False, transform=trans, download=True)

batch_size = 64

train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                 dataset=train_set,
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 shuffle=True)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                dataset=test_set,
                batch_size=batch_size,
shuffle=True)

class NeuralNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NeuralNet, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(28*28, 500)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(500, 256)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 2)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = x.view(-1, 28*28)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

num_epochs = 2
random_sample_size = 200

values_0_or_1 = [t for t in train_set if (int(t[1]) == 0 or int(t[1]) == 1)]
values_0_or_1_testset = [t for t in test_set if (int(t[1]) == 0 or int(t[1]) == 1)]

print(len(values_0_or_1))
print(len(values_0_or_1_testset))

train_loader_subset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                 dataset=values_0_or_1,
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 shuffle=True)

test_loader_subset = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
                 dataset=values_0_or_1_testset,
                 batch_size=batch_size,
                 shuffle=False)

train_loader = train_loader_subset

# Hyper-parameters 
input_size = 100
hidden_size = 100
num_classes = 2
# learning_rate = 0.00001
learning_rate = .0001
# Device configuration
device = 'cpu'
print_progress_every_n_epochs = 1

model = NeuralNet().to(device)

# Loss and optimizer
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)  

N = len(train_loader)
# Train the model
total_step = len(train_loader)

most_recent_prediction = []
test_actual_predicted_dict = {}

rm = random.sample(list(values_0_or_1), random_sample_size)
train_loader_subset = data_utils.DataLoader(rm, batch_size=4)

weights_without_clone = []
weights_with_clone = []

for i in range(0 , 2) : 
    for epoch in range(num_epochs):
        for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader_subset):  
            # Move tensors to the configured device
            images = images.reshape(-1, 2).to(device)
            labels = labels.to(device)

            # Forward pass
            outputs = model(images)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)

            # Backward and optimize
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        if (epoch) % print_progress_every_n_epochs == 0:
            print ('Epoch [{}/{}], Step [{}/{}], Loss: {:.4f}'.format(epoch+1, num_epochs, i+1, total_step, loss.item()))


    print('model fc2 weights ' , model.fc2.weight.data)
    weights_without_clone.append(model.fc2.weight.data)
    weights_with_clone.append(model.fc2.weight.data.clone())
```

Output of model :

```
12665
2115
Epoch [1/2], Step [50/198], Loss: 0.0968
Epoch [2/2], Step [50/198], Loss: 0.0082
model fc2 weights  tensor([[-3.9507e-02, -4.0454e-02,  3.5576e-03,  ...,  6.2181e-03,
          4.1372e-02, -6.2960e-03],
        [ 1.8778e-02,  2.7049e-02, -3.5624e-02,  ...,  2.6797e-02,
          2.2041e-03, -4.2284e-02],
        [ 1.9571e-02, -3.2545e-02,  2.6618e-02,  ..., -1.6139e-02,
          4.1192e-02, -2.3458e-02],
        ...,
        [-4.6123e-03,  2.6943e-02,  3.9979e-02,  ..., -3.3848e-02,
          3.6096e-02,  2.4211e-02],
        [-1.4698e-02,  9.7528e-04, -2.5244e-03,  ..., -3.3145e-02,
          1.0888e-02,  3.1091e-02],
        [-1.7451e-02, -2.1646e-02,  2.5885e-02,  ...,  4.0453e-02,
         -6.5324e-03, -3.5410e-02]])
Epoch [1/2], Step [50/198], Loss: 0.0025
Epoch [2/2], Step [50/198], Loss: 0.0013
model fc2 weights  tensor(1.00000e-02 *
       [[-3.9891, -4.0454,  0.3558,  ...,  0.7168,  4.1902, -0.6253],
        [ 1.8766,  2.7049, -3.5632,  ...,  2.6785,  0.2192, -4.2297],
        [ 2.1426, -3.2545,  2.6621,  ..., -1.6285,  4.1196, -2.2653],
        ...,
        [-0.4930,  2.6943,  3.9971,  ..., -3.2940,  3.6641,  2.4248],
        [-1.5160,  0.0975, -0.2524,  ..., -3.1938,  1.1753,  3.1065],
        [-1.8116, -2.1646,  2.5883,  ...,  4.1355, -0.5921, -3.5416]])
```

Printing the values of `weights_without_clone` :

```
print(weights_without_clone[0])
print(weights_without_clone[1])
```

outputs :

```
tensor(1.00000e-02 *
       [[-3.9891, -4.0454,  0.3558,  ...,  0.7168,  4.1902, -0.6253],
        [ 1.8766,  2.7049, -3.5632,  ...,  2.6785,  0.2192, -4.2297],
        [ 2.1426, -3.2545,  2.6621,  ..., -1.6285,  4.1196, -2.2653],
        ...,
        [-0.4930,  2.6943,  3.9971,  ..., -3.2940,  3.6641,  2.4248],
        [-1.5160,  0.0975, -0.2524,  ..., -3.1938,  1.1753,  3.1065],
        [-1.8116, -2.1646,  2.5883,  ...,  4.1355, -0.5921, -3.5416]])
tensor(1.00000e-02 *
       [[-3.9891, -4.0454,  0.3558,  ...,  0.7168,  4.1902, -0.6253],
        [ 1.8766,  2.7049, -3.5632,  ...,  2.6785,  0.2192, -4.2297],
        [ 2.1426, -3.2545,  2.6621,  ..., -1.6285,  4.1196, -2.2653],
        ...,
        [-0.4930,  2.6943,  3.9971,  ..., -3.2940,  3.6641,  2.4248],
        [-1.5160,  0.0975, -0.2524,  ..., -3.1938,  1.1753,  3.1065],
        [-1.8116, -2.1646,  2.5883,  ...,  4.1355, -0.5921, -3.5416]])
```

Printing the values of `weights_with_clone` :

```
print(weights_with_clone[0])
print(weights_with_clone[1])
```

outputs :

```
tensor([[-3.9507e-02, -4.0454e-02,  3.5576e-03,  ...,  6.2181e-03,
          4.1372e-02, -6.2960e-03],
        [ 1.8778e-02,  2.7049e-02, -3.5624e-02,  ...,  2.6797e-02,
          2.2041e-03, -4.2284e-02],
        [ 1.9571e-02, -3.2545e-02,  2.6618e-02,  ..., -1.6139e-02,
          4.1192e-02, -2.3458e-02],
        ...,
        [-4.6123e-03,  2.6943e-02,  3.9979e-02,  ..., -3.3848e-02,
          3.6096e-02,  2.4211e-02],
        [-1.4698e-02,  9.7528e-04, -2.5244e-03,  ..., -3.3145e-02,
          1.0888e-02,  3.1091e-02],
        [-1.7451e-02, -2.1646e-02,  2.5885e-02,  ...,  4.0453e-02,
         -6.5324e-03, -3.5410e-02]])
tensor(1.00000e-02 *
       [[-3.9891, -4.0454,  0.3558,  ...,  0.7168,  4.1902, -0.6253],
        [ 1.8766,  2.7049, -3.5632,  ...,  2.6785,  0.2192, -4.2297],
        [ 2.1426, -3.2545,  2.6621,  ..., -1.6285,  4.1196, -2.2653],
        ...,
        [-0.4930,  2.6943,  3.9971,  ..., -3.2940,  3.6641,  2.4248],
        [-1.5160,  0.0975, -0.2524,  ..., -3.1938,  1.1753,  3.1065],
        [-1.8116, -2.1646,  2.5883,  ...,  4.1355, -0.5921, -3.5416]])
```

Why is `1.00000e-02 *` prepended to the final weight value of the second model ?

Why is using `clone()` required in order to add final weights for each iteration as omitting `clone()` the same weights are added to each iteration ? :

```
weights_without_clone.append(model.fc2.weight.data)
weights_with_clone.append(model.fc2.weight.data.clone())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am going to reproduce your case. I will use very simple model:

Code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim

torch.manual_seed(42)

# Some dummy data:
X = torch.randn(100, 5, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)
Y = torch.randn(100, 5, requires_grad=True, dtype=torch.float)


class Model(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(5, 5, bias=False)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(5, 5, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x


def train(model, x, y, loss_fn, optimizer, n_epochs=1000, print_loss=True):

    weights = []

    for i in range(n_epochs):
        y_hat = model(x)
        loss = loss_fn(y_hat, y)

        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss.backward()

        if print_loss:
            print(f'| {i+1} | Loss: {loss.item():.4f}')

        optimizer.step()

        print('W:\n', model.fc2.weight.data)

        weights.append(model.fc2.weight.data)

    return weights


torch.manual_seed(42)

model = Model()

loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01)
n_epochs = 2

weights = train(model=model,
                      x=X,
                      y=Y,
                      loss_fn=loss_fn,
                      optimizer=optimizer,
                      n_epochs=n_epochs,
                      print_loss=True)
```

Output:

```py
| 1 | Loss: 1.0285
W:
 tensor([[-0.2052, -0.1257, -0.2684,  0.0425, -0.4413],
        [ 0.4034, -0.3797,  0.3448,  0.0741, -0.1450],
        [ 0.2759,  0.0695,  0.3608,  0.0487, -0.1411],
        [ 0.1201, -0.1213,  0.1881,  0.3990,  0.2583],
        [-0.1956,  0.2581,  0.0798,  0.2270, -0.2725]])
| 2 | Loss: 1.0279
W:
 tensor([[-0.2041, -0.1251, -0.2679,  0.0428, -0.4410],
        [ 0.4030, -0.3795,  0.3444,  0.0738, -0.1447],
        [ 0.2755,  0.0693,  0.3603,  0.0484, -0.1411],
        [ 0.1200, -0.1213,  0.1879,  0.3987,  0.2580],
        [-0.1958,  0.2580,  0.0796,  0.2269, -0.2725]])
```

Ok, it works well. Let's now look at `weights`:

Code:

```py
print(*weights, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```py
tensor([[-0.2041, -0.1251, -0.2679,  0.0428, -0.4410],
        [ 0.4030, -0.3795,  0.3444,  0.0738, -0.1447],
        [ 0.2755,  0.0693,  0.3603,  0.0484, -0.1411],
        [ 0.1200, -0.1213,  0.1879,  0.3987,  0.2580],
        [-0.1958,  0.2580,  0.0796,  0.2269, -0.2725]])
tensor([[-0.2041, -0.1251, -0.2679,  0.0428, -0.4410],
        [ 0.4030, -0.3795,  0.3444,  0.0738, -0.1447],
        [ 0.2755,  0.0693,  0.3603,  0.0484, -0.1411],
        [ 0.1200, -0.1213,  0.1879,  0.3987,  0.2580],
        [-0.1958,  0.2580,  0.0796,  0.2269, -0.2725]])
```

Ok, it is not what we want, but actually it is expected behavior. If you look once again, you will see that values in the list correspond to weights values from second epoch. That means we were appending not new tensors, but assignments that point to real weights storage, and that's why we just have the same final results.

In other words, you are getting the same values when using regular append, because gradients still propagate to the original weights tensor. And appended "weights tensors" are pointing to the same tensor from model that changes during backprop.

That's why you need to use `clone` to create a new tensor, **BUT** it is recommended to use `tensor.clone().detach()` whereas `clone` is recorded to computational graph, this means if you backprop through this cloned tensor,

> Gradients propagating to the cloned tensor will propagate to the original tensor. [clone docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html?highlight=clone#torch.Tensor.clone)

So, if you want to append your weights safely use this:

```py
weights.append(model.fc2.weight.data.clone().detach())
```